# how to get a php form work on google cloud instance?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I have a static website website with a simple php form, it shows the sent message but i don't get any email

I'm using Google cloud instance, Cloudflare and Zoho mail service,
Everything was working fine on OVH VPS, and since i moved to Google cloud it stopped working

does google stop something that is used to send this email?

And this is my php code:

```
    <?php   
    if(empty($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) == 0 || empty($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) == 0 || empty($_POST['subject']) && strlen($_POST['subject']) == 0 || empty($_POST['message']) && strlen($_POST['message']) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $to = 'support@mydomain.com'; // Email submissions are sent to this email

    // Create email 
    $email_subject = "Project Message";
    $email_body = "<h1>You have received a new project.</h1><br><br>".
                  "<b>Name</b>: $name <br>
                  <b>Company</b>: $company <br>
                  <b>Email</b>: $email <br>
                  <b>Subject</b>: $subject <br>
                  <b>Message</b>: $message<br><br>";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";   
    $headers .= "From: Service Portale<sales@mydomain.com>\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email"; 
    
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); // Post message
    return true;            
    ?>
```

Comment: have you tested sending the most basic email using the most basic script from your Google Cloud site to eliminate possible problems with the above code? If a basic email fails then it is likely that google are blocking it

Comment: yes i did a simple page with only the basics, and it doesn't send anything

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation [Sending email from an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail):

> By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports
> but **port 25**, which **is blocked** because of the risk of abuse.
> All other ports are open, including ports 587 and 465.
>
> **Note**: *Port 25 is always blocked and can't be used, even through an SMTP relay using G Suite*.

This is probably the issue that you're running into.

**To solve this issue** you should follow documentation [SMTP Server Configuration - Zoho Mail](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html) section "Unable to connect to Outgoing Server/ SMTP Server":

> Sometimes, the email clients connect to the default port 25 when
> connecting to the SMTP server. In case of Zoho Mail, you need to
> connect to smtp.zoho.eu in SSL or TLS ports i.e 465 or 587
> respectively.

[Here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md#a-simple-example) you can find an example based on [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md).